# « N'oublie pas ta froc sur le dossier de la chaise là ! » : raison (origine) d'un emploi au féminin au Québec pour le manteau ?

Tags: étymologie, genre, québec, régionalismes, origine-ou-raison

Un Québécois me dit avoir vu aux États-Unis le mot [*frock*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/frock?s=t) être employé en langue anglaise dans un contexte industriel, ce qui lui rappelle l'emploi de *froc* au Québec dans le sens de « manteau » par un membre plus âgé de sa famille, aussi Québécois, et c'est non sans rappeler l'attestation, antérieure à l'habit de moine isolée de *froc* pour manteau de 1138 (DHLF/Rey). Je me rends compte que je partage aussi la connaissance de ce sens-là lorsque j'en discute avec quelqu'un d'autre, aussi Québécois, comme moi-même le suis-je d'ailleurs. Puis finalement je me rappelle que c'est employé au féminin soit « ta froc », tel que l'indique le [*Wiktionnaire*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/froc#Nom_commun_2), qui indique de surcroît la mention de la région de la *Gaspésie* (qui n'est pas la région d'où proviendrait la personne dont il est fait mention en intro., ni la mienne).

---

Au [*GPFC*](http://bibnum2.banq.qc.ca/bna/numtxt/179630.pdf) (*Glossaire du parler français au Canada, 1930*), on indique substantif féminin et masculin à *froc* avant de présenter trois acceptions :

- Tout d'abord l'« espèce de *blouse* ample que portent les paysans,
  les ouvriers » avec un seul exemple au masculin, *mettre son froc pour
  aller travailler*, et on a la mention dialecte référant à une
  prononciation *fro* pour le gros drap de qualité inférieure de
  Normandie, utilisé à l'époque pour la confection de vêtement de
  moines nous dit-on.
- Puis en deuxième lieu on a le *tricot/gilet tricoté*.
- Et enfin la *redingote* (et celle de d'écolier), et on ajoute une
  reférence à l'emploi de *frockcoat* et *prince-albert* au Canada.

Les génériques sous-jacents seraient donc ce qu'on entendait à l'époque
   de la *blouse* (n. f.), du *gilet* (n. m.) et de la *redingote* (n.
   f.).

---

La mention Gaspésie à l'entrée de [froc](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/froc#Nom_commun_2) au *Wiktionnaire* laisse penser que l'emploi, voire son origine, serait régional(e) : est-ce bien le cas ?

- L'emploi au féminin (*ta froc*) pour le « manteau » est-il entendu ou compris à Québec et Montréal aujourd'hui, est-ce associé à un registre particulier ou perçu comme étant régional ?
- L'emploi au féminin s'explique-t-il par un des génériques sous-jacents aux sens présentés au QPFC pour *froc* ; d'où provient cet emploi, s'appuie-t-il sur un des trois sens présentés, est-ce un emprunt à l'anglais, l'emploi en Gaspésie est-il un emploi différent de celui que je connais et pourquoi le  féminin ?

Comment: En France on emploie « froc » pour désigner un pantalon, comme dans les expressions : « Baisser son froc » (se soumettre)  ou « Faire dans son froc » (Avoir peur).

Comment: frock en anglais [GB] est une **robe**. Aux EUA, je ne l'entends pas.

Answer (score 2):

L’image du bûcheron ou du coureur des bois canadien avec sa chemise rouge à carreaux est probablement presque aussi célèbre que celle de l’agent de la Gendarmerie Royale du Canada avec son chapeau sur son cheval, et une [recherche d’images par Google](https://www.google.ca/search?q=bucheron+canadien&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhg8OU59rYAhVMkeAKHVM9CkMQ_AUICigB&biw=1378&bih=828) est une manière comme une autre de constater l’omniprésence de ce stéréotype.

Lorsque je demeurai à Québec, il y a un quart de siècle, j’ai été exposé pour la seule et unique fois de mon existence à l’utilisation systématique du mot ***froc*** pour désigner un objet, cette chemise de bûcheron en l’occurrence, et l’on utilisait pour ce faire le féminin : ***une froc à carreaux*** ou ***une froc carreautée***.

Je vois difficilement comment quelqu’un ne ferait pas immédiatement le lien entre la notion expliquée et l’objet, puisque le motif de la froc était toujours spécifié. Je n’ai pas eu l’occasion d’entendre ***froc*** désigner autre chose que ce vêtement, mais je suppose que j’aurais compris qu’il s’agissait d’un manteau quelconque.

Ce mot à ma connaissance n’est guère utilisé dans l’Ouest du Québec, mais il y demeurerait sans doute compréhensible à peu d’explications près, ne serait-ce que par le lien étymologique que l’on peut faire avec le verbe *défroquer* ou l’adjectif *défroqué*.

Answer (score 1):

Jamais entendu le mot Froc de la bouche d'un québécois, et ca fait 20 ans que je vis à Montréal. 
Quand à l'emploi du féminin, c'est une faute courante au Québec de féminiser des mots. Il n'st pas rare d'entendre une avion, une ascenseur, une autobus, une aéroport, etc.

Comment: Le changement de genre décrit ici découle de l'ancienne homophonie entre une et un suivit d'une voyelle et ne touche que les mots avec une initiale vocalique, ce qui n'est pas le cas de *froc*.

Comment: Une faute ????   Faute par rapport à quoi ? Dire que c'est une faute c'est émettre un jugement moral. La seule chose qu'on puisse dire c'est qu'il y a divergence entre le français européen et le français québécois. L'un aurait-il une plus grande valeur morale que l'autre ?

Answer (score 1):

J’sus acadien du nord du Nouveau-Brunswick, d’un village peuplé en partie du village acadien de Carleton et j’utilise le mot froc pour un manteau! J’vois pas de lien évident dans les glossaires acadiens ou les différents patois d’origines, donc (dabord) y a des bonnes chances que c’est un nouveau mot de Carleton! Un des rares qu’on peut pas retracer au Poitou! À date en tout cas…

Comment: Salut ! Et dans une phrase tu emploies ça au masculin ou au féminin « froc » ? Penses-tu que tu emploies plus souvent « froc » que _manteau_ et l'emploierais-tu dans un contexte formel ? Dirais-tu « froc » pour _salopette_, ou un genre d'_overall_, ou pour un morceau de vêtement généralement (une chemise ?) ? Merci !

Comment: Je ne sais pas si l'orthographe de votre réponse a été choisie exprès ou non ?